# all input arrays must have the same dimensions - python using append

Tags: numpy, append

import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [[5,6,7,8],[9,0,1,2]]

j = np.append(x,y,axis=0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5147, in
 append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: There is just too much code here. Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?

Comment: `np.append` is hard to use correctly, and inefficient when used in a loop. Use list `append`, and make the array once, after the loop.

Comment: You could try `j = np.append (root[None], [left_tree, right_tree], axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks +COLDSPEED i have reduced my code to a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.